# How to create image gallery with caption and hover effect

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new in bootstrap and css and i want to create image gallery with caption and hover and i dont know how to do. so i have **attach image** here which i need to create exactly to complete my task and also i have try a code which is attach here.

```
please help me to create it
```

[image: I want to do exactly appear in screen shot image][image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjLHE.png)

HTML Code:

```
 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="product-wrapper">
                            <div class="thumb">
                                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                    <img src="images/product1.png" alt="">
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="caption">
                                <p>H.D.P.E pipes</p>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="">
                            <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                <img src="images/product2.png" alt="">
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <p>H.D.P.E pipes</p>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="">
                            <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                <img src="images/product3.png" alt="">
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <p>H.D.P.E pipes</p>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="">
                            <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                <img src="images/product4.png" alt="">
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <p>H.D.P.E pipes</p>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

CSS:

.product-wrapper
{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px #5e5e5e;
    z-index: 198;
}
.product-wrapper .caption
{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 3%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #eee;
    background: #42B32F;
    z-index: 199;
}
```

Comment: Edit your answer, I can't understand, where is the image? And the code ? Maybe a jsfiddle ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjLHE.png this is image link i want to create same as in this image (Reference Img)

Comment: There is no image attached with this question.However if you are looking for image gallery with caption this(http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp) might help you.If this is not what you want then please edit the question

Comment: Can you make the jsfiddle so that we can review it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/stbqtthr/  

this is what i had tried but it is not effective

Comment: @iron3795 Go through this [Link](https://miketricking.github.io/dist/) may be this is the thing which you want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the demo , i have updated your code, is this what you need ?

```css
p {
 margin:0;
}
.product-wrapper {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-radius: 2px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px #5e5e5e;
 z-index: 198;
 margin:11px 0;
}
.product-wrapper .caption {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 15px 3%;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 line-height: 18px;
 font-size: 11px;
 color: #eee;
 background: #42B32F;
 z-index: 199;
 text-align:center;
}
.product-wrapper img , .thumb a , .thumb a img {
 width:100%;
}
.product-wrapper img {
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 -webkit-transition:all .4s linear;
 transition:all .4s linear;
}
.product-wrapper:hover img {
 -ms-transform:scale(1.2);
 -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
 transform:scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="container">

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="thumb"> <a href="#" target="_blank"> <img src="https://images2.alphacoders.com/303/thumb-1920-30312.jpg" alt=""> </a> </div>
    <div class="caption">
      <p>H.D.P.E pipes</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="thumb"> <a href="#" target="_blank"> <img src="https://images2.alphacoders.com/303/thumb-1920-30312.jpg" alt=""></a> </div>
    <div class="caption">
      <p>H.D.P.E pipes</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="thumb"> <a href="#" target="_blank"> <img src="https://images2.alphacoders.com/303/thumb-1920-30312.jpg" alt=""> </a> </div>
    <div class="caption">
      <p>H.D.P.E pipes</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="thumb"> <a href="#" target="_blank"> <img src="https://images2.alphacoders.com/303/thumb-1920-30312.jpg" alt=""> </a> </div>
    <div class="caption">
      <p>H.D.P.E pipes</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```